# Window "Title" Binds but not Window Width and Height

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I wanted to have my View Model Manage my Window Title and Size:  Title is binding Fine. Size not so much.  any help will be appreciated.

```
<Window x:Class="Sweeper.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Sweeper"
        xmlns:mouse="clr-namespace:Sweeper.MouseBehavior"
        xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
        Title="{Binding Path=Title, FallbackValue='MainWindowXX'}" 
        Height     ="{Binding Path=Height,    FallbackValue = 200}" 
        Width      ="{Binding Path=Width,     FallbackValue = 250}"          
        Background ="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FFD2F4CC">
...
</Window>
```

///// Snippet from my VM

```
public int Height
{
    get { return height; }
    set { height = value;
          OnPropertyChanged("Height");
    }
}
private int width = 400;

public int Width
{
    get { return width; }
    set
    {
        width = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Width");
    }
}

string title = "Mark's Sweeper Game";

public string Title
{
    get { return title; }
    set { title = value; OnPropertyChanged("Title"); }
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "not so much". Describe _exactly_ what happens, and how this is different from what you expect. Please also provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem. As far as the code you posted so far goes, you aren't showing anything that would set the `height` field of your view model class; maybe you just failed to include that, or maybe that's your bug. Impossible to say without a clearer question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Mode=TwoWay in the binding.

```
Height     ="{Binding Path=Height,  Mode=TwoWay,  FallbackValue = 200}" 
Width      ="{Binding Path=Width,  Mode=TwoWay,   FallbackValue = 250}"
```

Comment: Only option I have is 1) Vote Up 2) Vote Down 3) Share 4) Edit  :(